# Copying Account Address to Contact Address

Tags: trigger, field-update

I am trying copy the address from account to contact after updating. But after update the address in contact is still the same. I could not figure out why. Any insights would be appreciated.

```
trigger UpdateAddress on Account (after update) {
 for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
     List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT accountId, 
                            Account.BillingStreet, 
                            Account.BillingCity, 
                            Account.BillingState, 
                            Account.BillingPostalCode, 
                            Account.BillingCountry 
                          FROM Contact];

      for (Contact c : contacts) {
          c.MailingStreet     = c.Account.BillingStreet;
          c.MailingCity       = c.Account.BillingCity;
          c.MailingState      = c.Account.BillingState;
          c.MailingPostalCode = c.Account.BillingPostalCode;
          c.MailingCountry    = c.Account.BillingCountry;
          update c;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Trigger is fired on Account, but Contact is queried without referring the Account in current trigger context.   Also, SOQL, DML should NOT be inside loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would query all the child Contacts of the Accounts that are updated (the code in the question queries every Contact in the system for every Account that is changing) and copy the address fields:

```
trigger UpdateAddress on Account (after update) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        Account old = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);
        if (a.BillingStreet != old.BillingStreet || ...) {
            accountIds.add(a.Id);
        }
    }
    if (accountIds.size() > 0) {
        Contact[] updates = [
                select Id, AccountId
                from Contact
                where AccountId in :accountIds
                ];
        for (Contact c : updates) {
            Account a = Trigger.newMap.get(c.AccountId);
            c.BillingStreet = a.BillingStreet;
            ...
        }
        update updates;
    }
}
```

But governor limits may be a problem as 100 Accounts could have 1000 Contacts each and so cause [DML limit](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) to be exceeded.

The check on the Account address fields aims to avoid the Contact query and DML when other fields change.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues with your trigger. You shouldn't perform SOQL or DML inside for loops. Please refer the following code

```
Trigger UpdateAddressOnContact on Account (after update) {

    Set<Id> accountIds = Trigger.newMap.keySet();
    //query contacts related to triggering accounts
    List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT accountId, <other additional fields> FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds] 

    Account a;
    for(Contact c : contacts) {
        a = Trigger.newMap.get(c.AccountId);
        c.MailingStreet     = a.BillingStreet;
        c.MailingCity       = a.BillingCity;
        c.MailingState      = a.BillingState;
        c.MailingPostalCode = a.BillingPostalCode;
        c.MailingCountry    = a.BillingCountry;
    }
    update contacts;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is still throwing an DML exception error. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger adresscupdate on account (after update) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (account a : trigger.new) {
        account old = trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);
        if (a.billingstreet != old.billingstreet|| a.billingcity !=old.billingcity || a.billingstate !=old.billingstate || a.billingcountry != old.billingcountry) {
            accountIds.add(a.Id);
        }
    }
    if (accountIds.size() > 0) {
        contact[] updates = [select Id, accountId from contact where accountId in :accountIds];
        for (contact c : updates) {
            account a = trigger.newmap.get(c.accountId);
            c.mailingStreet = a.billingStreet;
            c.mailingcity = a.billingcity;
            c.mailingstate = a.billingstate;
            c.mailingpostalcode = a.billingpostalcode;
            c.mailingcountry = a.billingcountry;
                    }
        update updates;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [answer]. Please **[edit]** your post to provide some text explaining why it in fact answers the question (if it does).